# ImportError: No module named pandas on vscode, but no errors on Idle or terminal

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa62G.png)

when I am trying to import pandas module in vscode (python environment). This happened. But I do can import pandas in IDLE or terminal.

When I run `python3 -m pip install pandas` it says the package is already installed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYNpH.png)

Comment: When using vscode, make sure you set the right Python workspace in the lower left corner.  You might be using a different Python than what is defaulted in the terminal.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: which os you are using?

Answer (score 0):

for vscode default python interpreter is python2 you have to change to python3